# Template argument deduction of custom allocator

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction

There is a custom allocator class:

```
template<typename T>
class pool_allocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = value_type *;

    /* Default constructor */
    constexpr pool_allocator( void ) noexcept = default;

    /* Converting constructor used for rebinding */
    template<typename U>
    constexpr pool_allocator( const pool_allocator<U> & ) noexcept {}

    [[nodiscard]] pointer allocate( size_t n, [[maybe_unused]] const pointer hint = nullptr ) const noexcept {
        return get_pool().allocate( n );
    }

    void deallocate( pointer ptr, size_t n ) noexcept {
        get_pool().deallocate( ptr, n );
    }

private:
    template<size_t CAPACITY>
    memory_pool<value_type, CAPACITY> & get_pool( void ) noexcept;
};
```

The `pool_allocator` serves as the allocator to a `memory_pool` implementation:

```
template<typename T, size_t CAPACITY>
class memory_pool {
public:
    using element_type = T;
    using pointer = element_type *;
    static constexpr size_t capacity { CAPACITY };

    [[nodiscard]] inline pointer allocate( [[maybe_unused]] size_t n = 1 ) noexcept { ... }

    inline void deallocate( pointer ptr, [[maybe_unused]] size_t n = 1 ) noexcept { ... }
};
```

The problem is there are many instantiations of memory pool for particular type of various sizes. For instance:

```
struct sample { /* ... */ };

memory_pool<sample, 10> m_samples;  /* Serves for 10 instances of 'sample' type */
```

Once tried to use the `pool_allocator` to allocate the instance from the `m_samples` pool:

```
allocator_traits<pool_allocator<sample>>::allocate( pool_allocator<sample> {}, 1 );
```

It is required to "link" concrete `memory_pool` instance with the allocator. Let's consider, the type `T` matches every time, but the allocator shall not be aware of the `memory_pool` capacity. So my thoughts were to declare a getter for particular `memory_pool` type `get_pool()` - to declare it within the allocator but to have it defined in a .cpp file to implement the link, something like:

.cpp:

```
template<> template<>
memory_pool<sample, 10> & pool_allocator<sample>::get_pool( void ) noexcept {
    return m_samples; /* The instance being created before */
}
```

So my question is: How to make this implemented? Simply to have the option to use type specific `pool_allocator<sample>` to operate with concrete `memory_pool` instance for the same type but not to specify the capacity as explicit `pool_allocator` template parameter... to make it deduced? To use delegate/function pointer instead? Any other way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple (only important parts are listed):

```
template<typename T>
class pool_allocator {
public:

    [[nodiscard]] pointer allocate( size_t n, [[maybe_unused]] const pointer hint = nullptr ) const noexcept {
        return get_pool().allocate( n );
    }

    void deallocate( pointer ptr, size_t n ) noexcept {
        get_pool().deallocate( ptr, n );
    }

private:
    static auto & get_pool( void ) noexcept; /* <-- here it comes */
};
```

and then somewhere in a .cpp file, specialize the `get_pool()` static member for particular type:

```
template<>
auto & pool_allocator<sample>::get_pool( void ) noexcept {
    return m_samples;
}
```

So simple auto declaration does the trick. Maybe the next step to improve would be to constrain the `get_pool()` return value by a concept, but it is another story...